# gegs? (9, 4) - a british cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

> gegs? (9, 4)

I hope this is a suitable forum for this British crossword clue, as it's my first post and I'm trying something new. This is a cryptic crossword clue, so (9, 4) tells you about the structure of the answer.

Bonus question:

> `D R U G G E D   U P? (6, 3)`

Comment: I remember this from a TV programme (could have been "drop the dead donkey"?) where a character was getting increasingly infuriated at this clue, but refused to let anyone else "help".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

gegs? (9, 4)

> **SCRAMBLED EGGS** 
>  The letter of "gegs" are those of the word "eggs" only mixed up (or *scrambled*). The answer is thus `scrambled eggs`. The question mark denotes that we are looking for something a little tricky. Normally a cryptic clue would want something like "Messy gegs for breakfast".

D R U G G E D   U P? (6, 3)

> **SPACED OUT** 
>  Notice there is a space between every letter. This means the letters are `spaced out` which is a synonym of being on drugs (or "drugged up").

Comment: the gegs one is very old and was originally presented as that. spaced out is also right so will accept when I can.

Comment: @MD-Tech Yes, nice. Maybe these cryptics should become more popular here. They don't fit anywhere else. Something people get here that they don't normally get using google is an explanation! Would you be inclined to raise this in meta? (I know many prominent members have posted about cryptics in the past)

Comment: @MD-Tech Actually never mind that. There is already a question over there which I will bump http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/213/on-the-posting-of-cryptic-crossword-clues-as-puzzles

Comment: I may well raise it as I'm interested - you may even start to get my crappy clues soon!

Comment: "Normally a cryptic clue would want something like 'gegs for breakfast'." Depending on the newspaper, that might still need a question mark. In *The Times*, for example, the convention is that a clue should contain both a definition and some wordplay leading you to the answer. "Gegs for breakfast" arguably contains neither so you'd still expect a question mark. Other newspapers use different conventions. (Actually, in *The Times*, I'd probably expect the clue to be written "Gegs! (9,4)", with the exclamation mark denoting that the clue should be interpreted "literally" in some sense.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, thanks for the useful commentary. I made a small edit which may improve it slightly

Answer (score -4):

> **gegs = scrambled eggs**

Note: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gegs%20crossword%20clue)

As for drugged up, I think I've actually done this one in the past (in [the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/cryptic/24950)). Answer was:

> **drugged up = zonked out**

Comment: I know the answers!

Comment: @MD-Tech: Still, probably not a great puzzle if it can be google in a single second...

Comment: fair enough - the other one may prove harder to google though. Zonked out is wrong.

Comment: @MD-Tech: My memory served me well, but if it didn't, it's [still an easy one to Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=drugged+up+(6%2C3)&oq=drugged+up+(6%2C3)&aqs=chrome..69i57.119j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=crossword+drugged+up+(6,3)&spell=1).

Comment: Any reason for downvote? Bearing in mind both answers are correct...

Comment: wasn't me downvoting so I don't know the reason but "Zonked out" is wrong...

Comment: it was because "Zonked Out" was wrong :p sorry. Also there is a culture of explanation being preferable over "here is the answer". You seem new so apologies I didn't notice that.

Comment: Both are correct. Your answer is one interpretation. I'd agree it's a better one, but the one I've cited is a previously used Cryptic crossword clue. Furthermore, the drugged out wasn't even the main question.

Comment: But then the spacing of "D R U G G E D  U P" would mean nothing (and that's quite against the philosophy of cryptics, isn't it?) Indeed, it wasn't even the main question. I reversed the downvote (sorry) :p

Comment: Fair enough. Don't be sorry, downvotes happen.

Comment: Yes, but they are deeply annoying for some people (like me at times)

Comment: Don't worry. I'll just serially downvote you in retribution :D Nah, honestly, don't worry - downvotes happen.