# A local puzzler lawyering around with a finish door

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here's a nice cryptic crossword clue for Puzzling SE:

> A local puzzler lawyering around with a finish door (7).

Comment: Just so I don't drive-by downvote with no comment: I downvoted only because I think single cryptic clues aren't really complete puzzles.

Comment: @DanRussell I was going to just do this in chat, but decided to post on the main site since there's a **long-standing precedent** for single cryptic clues posted here as puzzles (going way back to [the early days of the site](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5498/5373)). However, thank you for the explanation, and no hard feelings! :-)

Comment: Yep, and it's just my opinion, not something I think should be policy or anything.  And many of us in the US are wishing we'd had downvote power about 10 days ago...

Comment: I downvoted because there's no way to answer this without intimate knowledge of the community

Comment: Poor clue. "[W]ith a finish door" is ungrammatical and the tense of "lawyering" doesn't match the word clued by it.

Comment: @David "with a finish door" seems ungrammatical at first glance, but if one can talk about a finish line or a finish post, then why not a finish door?

Comment: @randal'thor Well, I suppose one can come up with a parsing of almost any sequence of words but that's super-contrived. Has the phrase ever been used in that sense? It's also very bad form to use the wrong word like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> me!
> "Lawyering around" clues an anagram of SUED; "OVI" is a door in Finnish. Putting those together gives DEUSOVI, a local puzzler!

Comment: Granted, if you wanted to sue someone you'd hire a lawyer, but how do you get from "lawyering" (which is in itself dubious -- verbing "lawyer") to the past participle "sued"?

Comment: @RosieF: The transitive verb "lawyer" can mean, essentially, "to unleash one's lawyer upon".

Answer (score 3):

NEW ANSWER:

The answer is

> Deusovi - a local puzzler (as realised by others, I didn't quite make it to the answer)

Because

> Contains SUED bacward - DEUS and OVI a door in Finnish

OLD ANSWER:

Is it

> Branded?

The Local Puzzler is

> @rand al'thor himself! No one more local than the poster. More commonly known as Rand

The finish door is

> Bed? (less sure)

And lawyering around suggests

> Bed fits around rand = **B**rand**ed**

Comment: Sorry, nope. 1) Why "lawyering"? 2) Why does "finish door" give "bed"? 3) Am I vain enough to make a puzzle about myself? :-)